# Javascript not called after back button is clicked

Tags: blazor-webassembly

In a Blazor WASM project I am calling a script that sets up some EventListeners. Everything works fine until I use the browsers back button to navigate or I go directly to a page using the address bar. It starts working again when I go back to the index/home page.

**Index.razor:**

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

@code{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("slideNav");
    }
}
```

**App.js:**

```
window.slideNav = () => {
    let mainElement = document.querySelector('#slider');
    let hamburgerMenu = document.querySelector('#hamburger-menu');
    let closeMenu = document.querySelector('#close-menu');
    let toggleNavBar = () => {
        mainElement.classList.toggle('opened-menu');
    };

    hamburgerMenu.addEventListener('click', toggleNavBar, false);
    closeMenu.addEventListener('click', toggleNavBar, false);
};
```

Any ideas?